# Select Query for duplicate values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

Using SQL Server 2000

I Want to Check the colum value whether it is same or not

Table1

```
ID Value

001 1000
002 1000
003 5000
```

From the above table, nothing display in the output, because values are differenct for each id.

If the values are same for all the id, then display otherwise nothing display.

How to make a select query.

Need Query Help

Comment: Same with what? What do you want to be displayed?

Comment: @Gopal: Please can you clarify what you want out of this query? You currently have two answers to this question, which do completely different things (based on their interpretations of your requirements.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code will look at the number of duplicate `Values` for an `ID`, and return:

`ID`, Duplicate `Value`, number of times this value exists in the table.

```
SELECT Id, Value
   , COUNT(1) AS occurances
FROM Table1
GROUP BY ID, VALUE
HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
```

Comment: @MarkBannister It is a little unclear what the OP really desires, which is why I tried to explain my query.  I didn't read the question until it was already edited, but I think the edit is accurate.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
select max(Value)
from Table1
having count(distinct Value) = 1
```

Comment: I think you are missing a `group by` and your having is wrong (`>1`)

Comment: @Hogan: No, you have misunderstood what the query is doing (although SQLServer might require a `group by ()`); it is returning a single value across the entire dataset, if all values of `Value` are the same across the entire dataset. (This is what the original question was asking for; Tevo D's edit makes it look like it is asking for something else.)